# Getting from ToManyField to Model values

Tags: tastypie

In django, I have two models - User and UserProfile. There may exist zero or one profiles for a particular user. I'm trying to include the information from the UserProfile model directly on the UserResource.

I would like to use the profile ToManyField, if it exists, to access the contents of the associated UserProfile model. I've tried a variety of things in dehydrate, including self.profile.get_related_resource(self) and UserProfile.objects.get(id=...), but I can't seem to find my way from the profile field to the model object. Can anybody help me out?

I'm still new to Python, Django, and Tastypie, so hopefully if I'm doing anything awful somebody will be kind enough to point it out.

The goal is to have JSON that looks like this:
{
    resourceUri: /v1/users/1
    date_of_birth: Jan 1, 1980
    ... etc
}

where date_of_birth is a property of the UserProfileResource. I don't want all of the fields from UserProfileResource, and I don't want the UserProfile to be a nested object in the response - I want some fields from UserProfileResource to be top-level fields in the response, so that they look like part of the User resource.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    profile = fields.ToOneField('foo.api.UserProfileResource', 'user', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        #etc...


class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    date_of_birth = ...
    #etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using Django 1.4 and [`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)?

Since the User:UserProfile relationship is 1:1 I would opt for the [ToOneField](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#toonefield) instead.  This will serialize as a URI pointer to your UserProfileResource (if one exists.)  If you'd like the UserProfileResource field data inline with your UserResource, you can specify [`full=True`](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#full) in the ToOneField definition.  With this method you should not need to override dehydrate.

Also, ensure that the second argument in the ToOneField definition is the User attribute which points to your UserProfile Django model.  For example if you have `OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')` in your Django model then this attribute should be `profile`.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    profile = fields.ToOneField('foo.api.UserProfileResource', 'profile', 
                                full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

---

If what you're after are specific fields from the UserProfile instance mixed in with your User, you should be able to do something like this:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    date_of_birth = fields.DateField('profile__date_of_birth', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        fields = ['userfields', 'gohere', 'date_of_birth']
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address my issue. The goal is to make parts of the UserProfileResource top-level fields of the UserResource response. I will clarify in an edit of the question.

Comment: Ah, you've brought me to another problem. The reason I was using ToManyField is that I can't get ToOneField to work, because the FK goes from UserProfile to User, not vice versa. I'm still playing around with that in another Thread in my head. :-)

Comment: @EricStein Yes, I have run into this myself.  I usually go the other way and create a UserProfileResource that references User.  If you do this you need to ensure you create UserProfiles for each User you want to access via the API, which isn't too difficult.  The reverse relation example (date_of_birth) should work either way though.